# Android Windows: When and how are they created?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layoutparams

I have read the standard Windows-related documentation and pawed through
a bunch of the source code in an attempt to understand how and when Android
Windows are created. I believe I have my arms around it and would like to
have it verified or corrected.

To my knowledge, there are only two ways to get a handle to a Window object.

```
1. Activity's getWindow.
2. Dialog's getWindow method.
```

In both of the above cases, you can get a handle to the Window using getWindow
and then manipulate the Window using the handle.

Windows can also be created by the use of WindowManager's addView method, but
it isn't possible to get a handle to such Windows. This is a very confusing area
because the addView method itself doesn't imply creating a Window and even the
comment for it in the View Manager source code just says the following.

```
Assign the passed LayoutParams to the passed View and add the view to
the window.
```

So it appears that the method is imply adding a View to your existing
Window.  However, the second parameter to addView is a
WindowManager.LayoutParams instance which, among other things, specifies a
Window type (e.g., TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT), implying that a Window is actually
getting created. This is, in fact, the case. Here's a very brief outline
of what happens in the source code. (For newbies: you can browse source
code on many different web sites; my favorite is http://grepcode.com.)

1. WindowManager implements the ViewManager interface, which is where
    addView is defined.
    URL: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/ViewManager.java#ViewManager.addView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29
2. The actual implementation of the WindowManager class is called
    WindowManagerImpl. It's addView calls WindowManagerGlobal's addView.
    URL: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/WindowManagerImpl.java#83
3. WindowManagerGlobal's addView is where the real work gets done.
    URL: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java#WindowManagerGlobal.addView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%2Candroid.view.Display%2Candroid.view.Window%29

   1. Verifies that the params passed in are a WindowManager.LayoutParams.
   2. Adjusts the layout parameters if the View has a parent.
   3. Determines if the new View (aka Window) is a panel Window
      (i.e., a Sub-window) or not and deals with that.
   4. Creates a new ViewRootImpl.
   5. Adds the View, ViewRootImpl and WindowManager.LayoutParams instances
      to separate ArrayLists.
   6. Adds the View and associated params to the ViewRootImpl via the
      latter's setView method.
4. ViewRootImpl's setView method then does a bunch of low-level work.
    It throws exceptions with variations on "Unable to add window..."
    messages in various error situations. According to the main comment for
    ViewRootImpl, it is "The top of a view hierarchy, implementing the
    needed protocol between View and the WindowManager. This is for the most
    part an internal implementation detail of WindowManagerGlobal."

   URL: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java#ViewRootImpl.setView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams%2Candroid.view.View%29

WindowManagerGlobal appears to track multiple Windows via the three arrays. As far as I can tell, the ViewRootImpl is effectively the new window and it is managed by WindowManagerGlobal.

Based on the above, it appears that calling addView does, in fact, create
a new window (although it is variously referred to as a view and a
window) but no associated Window class is provided to access it, so the
developer can't get a handle to it.

My questions are:

1. Are there ways to get a handle to a Window instance, other than the
    two getWindow methods mentioned above?
2. Does addView, in fact, create a Window and, if so, is there any way
    to get a handle to it?
3. Is anything else above incorrect and, if so, in what respect(s)?

Thanks!
Barry

Comment: I'm facing these same questions, did you ever find any answers to them?

Comment: In a word: "Nope."

Comment: That's a shame, thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: Yeah, I agree:-). NP.

Comment: No one has found the answer yet?